# Recognize Dial Tone from microphone or audio file

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft

I've googled a lot without having success in solving my problem. I need to recognize a dial tone in a wav file or directly from a microphone, or better: detect if the line (that is connected directly to the line-in of the audio card) is free.

In my Country (Italy) the dial tone is a sound wave of 425 Hz. My idea was to register from mic a 2s recording into a wav file, then load the data and apply a Discrete FFT, then search for that frequency in the results. However I've no idea on what to code that.

I have some problems:
1) Which DFT library to use
2) Conversions between byte and double
3) After the conversion is done, how to detect from Complex array if the wanted frequency is present

Code samples are welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are on the right track. [That's exactly how I would implement it]

Comment: FFT is probably overkill, a digital band-pass filter seems easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method for detecting the presence or absence of a specific tone is the [Goertzel Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm). This effectively just evaluates the DFT at the frequency of interest, which is a lot simpler and less computationally expensive than evaluating a complete FFT and then discarding all but one output bin.

There are numerous questions and answers on SO about using the Goertzel algorithm for tone detection, e.g. DTMF detection - you might want to study some of these, as they contain useful information and sample code.

Comment: Yes, very nice approach! Thank you!